# Elements missing when added to Set

Tags: java, collections

```
StringUtils.split(topic.getFirstorgroup(), ",")
```

returns a list of 47 elements.

```
apiFormatBooleanTopic.setTopics(Sets.newHashSet(StringUtils.split(topics.getFirstorgroup(), ",") );
```

But when am trying to add them in the method method which accepts set, the value that are added to the object are only 28, i wonder why the remaining are missing.

Comment: Can you debug and observe which ones are missing? Is it possible that they are the same as objects already present in the set?

Comment: You guys are correct..  the topics.getFirstorGroup() has duplicates, when i am adding them to arraylist like topics.addAll(Arrays.asList(booleansynset.getEntityList().split(","))); am getting all 47..  thanks for you suggestion guys....:)

Comment: One query i am left with is, does SET consider case sensitive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Set` can not hold duplicated entries. When you add an entry which is already contained the old one is replaced. (Think of it as keys of a `Map`). It is considered as "contained" if `equals()` of that object returns true.

Comment: +1 A set by definition can only hold unique elements.  IMHO, This is the whole point of using a Set instead of a List.